# Wordpress 2nd laugauge not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a simple wordpress site for the fist time.

I finish the Chinese version. It works find.

I then go on to make the english version.

I use the Specular Multi business theme and WPML to translate.

I spent a few days but still can not solve 2 problems.
when I finish the English content.

The Problems

1) The virtual path not working right

http://www.goodkompanion.com/en/?page_id=241
This should show the English content page.

http://www.goodkompanion.com/?page_id=241
I need to remove the en to show the correct content

2) The menu is in Chinese not english in the English Version.

---

I check the Appearance --> Menu 
The specular menu navigation only has one menu, no english menu.

There is a message on top saying.
Your theme supports 1 menu. Select which menu you would like to use.

Please tell me how to fix this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new menu, open up your theme's functions.php and look for:

```html
register_nav_menus
```

You should see something like

```html
register_nav_menus( array(
 'Main_Menu' => 'Navigation Menu',
) );
```

Simply add a new one like:

```html
register_nav_menus( array(
 'Main_Menu' => 'Navigation Menu',
 'footer_menu' => 'My Custom Footer Menu',
) );
```